# Pseudo element behind its element, when both elements are fixed?

Tags: css

Is it possible to use a before element for an overlay background on a nav, like this?

```css
.nav {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
}

.nav::before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  Nav content
</nav>
```

The issue I have is that the black overlay sits above the white nav, yet I want it behind? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Could you provide an example to what you would want to achieve (desired result) so that we can better understand how to help you? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `z-index`. Simply adding `z-index: -1` will make the main div show on top in your example

Comment: @Randommm this does not work

Comment: @panthro read the duplicate until the end to find the 3D solution (that's your only way to solve this case)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved with `isolation: isolate` along with a suitable positioning and z-index on the pseudo-element:

```css
.nav {
  /* to have the text stand out clearly */
  color: #fff;
  /* an easily-seen background for contrast
     in the demo: */
  background: #f00;
  /* just to better illustrate: */
  padding: 1rem;
  /* in order that the descendant pseudo-element
     is positioned in relation to this one:*/
  position: relative;
  /* to contain the stacking within the element,
     so that z-index: -1 on the pseudo-element
     doesn't place that pseudo-element behind
     its parent: */
  isolation: isolate;
}

.nav::before {
  content: '';
  /* for easy contrast for demonstration: */
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, black);
  /* in order to move the element out of
     the document flow, and to be positioned: */
  position: absolute;
  /* using 'inset' in place of 'top','right', 'bottom'
     and 'left': */
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  Nav content
</nav>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use z-index, i hope that its help you :)

```css
.nav {
      background: white;
          z-index:1;
}

.nav::before {
    content:"";
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    Nav content
</nav>
```

Comment: no need z-index for nav

Comment: @panthro it works as you described in the snippet, does it not? If it does not work in your case then you have not provided enough details of your version for us to fix it

Comment: This does not work, the nav element is also fixed.